# WinForms - DataGridView Inherits style from GroupBox

Tags: c#, datagridview, coding-style, groupbox

I have a weird problem, and I don't know if this is the default behaviour of .Net DataGridView inside a GroupBox/TabControl.

I've created a new WinForm project from scratch, and created a GroupBox(changed the text style). Like this:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/65f5f2762d.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/65f5f2762d.png)

Then, I've created a simple DataGridView, no font style at all, like this:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/09f55f951a.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/09f55f951a.png)

Then, in design mode, I dragged the DataGridView inside the GroupBox, and this sort of magic just happened:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d0334132f0.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d0334132f0.png)

My question is, can I disable this behaviour? Cause if I chage the DataGridView style outside the GroupBox and then drag it into, lost all the style.

Just for the record, this form has **NO CODE** at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also noticed this problem, most specifically with fonts.  It seems to be by design, but I have never had a non-default style get changed when dragging in, so that seems odd.  

The only way I have found to "disable" it was to change the property that was defaulted from the container once it was dragged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is known as [Ambient Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties.aspx). In short it is a mechanism where a control will "inherit" some property values from its parent, if the properties are not explicitly assigned to. I don't know of a way to prevent the behavior, other than assigning the wished values to the properties.

Answer (score 15):

Try putting a panel in the group box, then setting the font property of the panel.  This way the DataGridView will inherit the properties of the panel.  Much easier than setting every font property of the DataGridView.

Comment: GENIUS! I can't understand why this isn't marked as the answer!

Comment: Nice! It's a great and simple to implement solution. Saved me some time!